# How to control the visibility of panel in the second page based on the button click in the first page

Tags: asp.net, panel

I want to control the visibility of panel(true/false) in ASP.NET webforms based on a button click. If both the controls were in single page, I could have directly accessed it as `panel1.visible = true` in the button click event but button and panels are in different pages. On button click, I should redirect to a certain page and a certain panel should be made visible. How to achieve this.?

Comment: Easiest might be to use a `QueryString`. Your redirection to Page2 might look like this: `Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?show=true")`. Your Page2 `Load` function would check string `Request.QueryString["show"]` for value and show/hide accordingly. Another option would be to use `Session` if security is a concern.

Comment: Generally either put a flag on the query string or in session state.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `QueryString`

Redirection code to be behind your button

```
bool show = true; // Change accordingly
Response.Redirect("~/NextPage.aspx?show=" + show.ToString());
```

Retrieval code to be behind your destination page

```
protected void NextPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string qString = Request.QueryString["show"];

    if (qString != null)
    {
        MyPanel.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(qString);
    }
}
```